# Why does PDO 'execute' work irrespective of whether colon is included on a bound parameter variable?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on an application which uses PDO.

I've noticed that when binding parameters the query still works irrespective of whether I use or omit a colon on the bound parameter variable.

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . $this->table . "` WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $this->ci->db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([
     "id" => $id,
]);
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Gives exactly the same result as:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . $this->table . "` WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $this->ci->db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([
     ":id" => $id,
]);
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The difference (which might be hard to spot) is `"id" => $id` vs `":id" => $id`

So, which should be used? And is it the expected behaviour for them to give the same output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick glance at the PHP source code turns up [this code in `pdo_stmt.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L359) (this is the current master branch, so PHP 7.1, but I imagine it's fundamentally the same in all versions):

```
if (param->name) {
    if (is_param && ZSTR_VAL(param->name)[0] != ':') {
        zend_string *temp = zend_string_alloc(ZSTR_LEN(param->name) + 1, 0);
        ZSTR_VAL(temp)[0] = ':';
        memmove(ZSTR_VAL(temp) + 1, ZSTR_VAL(param->name), ZSTR_LEN(param->name) + 1);
        param->name = temp;
    } else {
        param->name = zend_string_init(ZSTR_VAL(param->name), ZSTR_LEN(param->name), 0);
    }
}
```

Roughly, the key part can be read as:

```
if ( char 0 of param->name is not ':' ) {
    set param->name to ':' concatenated with param->name
}
```

So, the form with the `:` on the front is the "correct" form, but if you pass any string without a `:` prefix, the PDO code will add one on internally, just to be user-friendly.

Note that this has nothing to do with how *arrays* work: the PHP array is just a way of getting a bunch of name-value pairs into the PDO code. It's the same as if an API accepted either the US spelling 'color' or the UK spelling 'colour' for a parameter; they're not "the same key", but the API can decide they have the same meaning.

In practice, the answer remains "use whichever you prefer".

Answer (score -1):

> Why does PDO query work irrespective

Because it's handy.

> So, which should be used?

One that suits you best.

> And is it the expected behaviour for them to give the same output?

Yes.

Comment: That seems a bit crazy though. In terms of a regular PHP array surely, `:id` and `id` would be considered as 2 different array keys because their names do not match?

Comment: And so what? I don't understand your problem, sorry.

Comment: @Andy Think of it as a "did you mean?" lookup: PDO will first look for the key `'id'`, and if it doesn't find it, look for `':id'` instead (I don't actually know if this is the algorithm used, but hopefully you get the idea). They're not the same parameter, but it doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: @Your Common Sense - Is your response to this serious? If you had an array in PHP such as `$data['id']` there's no way PHP would (or should) let you refer to it as `$data[':id']` because the keys are 2 totally different strings that do not match, i.e. they are not the same variable.

Comment: @Andy yes. Why would you refer it as $data[':id'] though? Just refer it as $data['id'] and your problem solved. any other questions?

Comment: Because according to what you just said it doesn't matter whether you include the : or not as PDO will treat it as the same thing. In my mind `id` and `:id` are not the same string and therefore do not reference the same thing. For example `$data['A']` and `$data['a']` are definitely not the same in terms of how standard PHP arrays work. But if PDO works that way, so be it.

Comment: @Andy you are confusing arrays with the way PDO is using them.